# Unity Parameter "Hash" does not exist

Tags: animation, unity3d-2dtools

In Unity 3D I am attempting to make transitions between character movement animations that get activated by pressing specific keys.  I am following a tutorial here so I can refer to it in order to double check for code misspellings or mistakes in animation editor, yet I find nothing that isn't done in the tutorial. So I am asking for help in figuring out what is wrong as I am coming up blank.

[animation editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb8Cr.png)

[2 warnings that keep appearing continuosly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X29zD.png)

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationState : MonoBehaviour
{

    Animator animator;
    int isWalkingHash;
    int isRunningHash;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        isWalkingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isWalking");
        isRunningHash = Animator.StringToHash("isRunning");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        bool isrunning = animator.GetBool(isRunningHash);  
        bool isWalking = animator.GetBool(isWalkingHash);
        bool forwardPressed = Input.GetKey("w");
        bool runPressed = Input.GetKey("left shift");

        if (!isWalking && forwardPressed)
        {
            animator.SetBool(isWalkingHash, true);
        }

        if (isWalking && !forwardPressed)
        {
            animator.SetBool(isWalkingHash, false);
        }

        if (!isrunning && (forwardPressed && runPressed))
        {
            animator.SetBool(isRunningHash, true);
        }

        if (isrunning && (!forwardPressed || !runPressed))
        {
            animator.SetBool(isRunningHash, false);
        }
    }
}
```